# Where the static variables are stored in Android?

Tags: java, android, static, multiprocessing

I have an application with 2 processes, one for Activity and one for Service.
Here is my Manifest:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.musicservicebymessenger.service.MusicService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":MusicService"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>
```

In MainActivity, I have a static variable like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    public static int a = 0;
}
```

And in Service I update like that:

```
public class MusicService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MainActivity.a++;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it works. I think 2 processes have 2 different heaps, so why one process can update the static variable in another process?

I had read some article and someone say that: Before Java 8, the Method area section (a part of PermGen) was used to store static variables of the class, metadata of the class, etc. Whereas, non-static methods and variables were stored in the heap memory. After the java 8 version, the PermGen has been replaced by MetaSpace, so the static variables are stored in the heap memory.

So Why the static variables are stored in Heap memory. what exactly area in which the static variables and methods are stored in heap memory? Why I can update it from another process?

Comment: "I don't understand why it works" -- how are you defining "works"? There are two copies of `MainActivity.a`, one in each process.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh, I don't know there are two copies of the static variable in 2 processes. Could you say more detail about that? How do the 2 processes sync the data? Can you refer to any document about that? Thanks!

Comment: "How do the 2 processes sync the data?" -- they don't. They are completely independent. Two processes running on one phone are no different than two processes running on separate phones, when it comes to RAM usage.